# Using wp_list_categories to show more than one custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, categories

I'm using wp_list_categories like this:

```
                                    $taxonomy     = 'colors';
                                    $orderby      = 'count';
                                    $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                                    $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                                    $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                                    $title        = '';
                                    $empty        = 0;
                                    $number       = 1;
                                    $style        = 'list';

                                    $args = array(
                                      'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                                      'orderby'      => $orderby,
                                      'show_count'   => $show_count,
                                      'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                                      'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                                      'title_li'     => $title,
                                      'hide_empty'   => $empty,
                                      'number'       => $number,
                                      'style'        => $style
                                    ); ?>


                                    <ul class="tax-ul">
                                        <li class="tax-header">Colors</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="list-cats">
                                        <?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
                                    </ul>
```

...but I have more than one taxonomy that I want to list.

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you turn $taxonomy into an array:

```
$taxonomy     = array('colors','additional-taxonomy', 'another-taxonomy', 'etc');
```

You should be set

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work.